# Doctrine2 + pdo_sqlsrv createQueryBuilder Order By com campo varchar não funciona

Tags: sql-server, pdo, doctrine-2, order-by, dql

Estou criando um método que recebe valores para createQueryBuilder () vindos por parâmetros.

Eu testei no meu banco de dados local com driver pdo_mysql e ele funcionou perfeitamente, ordenando tanto por um campo do tipo int (id) quanto por um campo do tipo varchar (titulo).

No entanto, depois de testar em outro banco de dados em um servidor externo com driver pdo_sqlsrv (e também driver sqlsrv) funciona quando o "order by" é por um campo do tipo int (id), mas quando a ordenação é por um campo do tipo varchar (titulo) dá timeout na conexão.

Segue o código os prints do retorno pelo banco mysql e pelo banco SqlServer:

```
public function getBy($fields, $orderBy, $where = null, $params = null)
{
    if (empty($where))
        $where = '1 = 1';

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select($fields)
        ->from($this->entity, $this->alias)
        ->where($where)
        ->add('orderBy', $orderBy)
        ->setFirstResult(URIHelper::$arrayParams['offset'])
        ->setMaxResults(URIHelper::$arrayParams['limit'])
        ->getQuery();

    if (!empty($params))
        $query->setParameters($params);

    print_r($query->getSQL());
    //print_r($query->getParameters());
    //print_r($query->getArrayResult());
    //die();
    return $query->getArrayResult();
}
```

---

**Retorno OK quando uso banco MySQL ordenação titulo(varchar):**

### [image: Retorno OK quando uso banco MySQL ordenação titulo(varchar):]

**Retorno OK quando uso banco SqlServer ordenação id(int):**

### [image: Retorno OK quando uso banco SqlServer ordenação id(int):]

**Retorno ERRO quando uso banco SqlServer ordenação titulo(varchar):**
[image: Retorno OK quando uso banco SqlServer ordenação titulo(varchar):]

Comment: SQL Server 2012? Qual a versão do driver `pdo_sqlsrv` que você tá usando?

Comment: SQL Server 2012, sim. Instalação e configuração pelo IIS 8, com PHP 5.4 e 5.6 e Driver 3.2 compatível com PHP 5.4 e 5.6. Mas não deve ser isso, senão não funcionaria a consulta ordenando pelo id também. Só não funciona quando ordena pelo titulo ou anuncio (ambos varchar).

Comment: Tenta configurar o IIS para um tempo de timeout maior. Em ***php.ini*** você aumenta `max_execution_time`, `max_input_time`, `default_socket_timeout`, `sqlsrv.connect_timeout` e `sqlsrv.timeout`. Talvez seja isso, já que o código retorna o Fatal Error lá embaixo falando em tempo máximo de execução excedido e na parte de cima aparece o erro `08S01` do ODBC 11. Tente otimixar sua *query* também.